# The Cox-Ingersoll-Ross Model (1985)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

Please show me how to solve (2) with computation processes.(1) was the initial question which I solved. I show the answers (1) below.

---

Consider the equation
\begin{eqnarray}
dr_t=(\alpha - \beta r_t ) dt + \sigma \sqrt{r_t} dB_t
\end{eqnarray}
which models the variations of the short rate process $r_t$, where $\alpha,  \beta, \sigma $ and $r_0$ are positive parameters. $B_t$ is a S.B.M.

---

(1) Compute $E[r_t | \mathcal{F}_s ]$ , $0 \le s \le t$.

---

(2) Compute $E[r_t^2 | \mathcal{F}_s ]$, $0 \le s \le t$.

(Thank you for your help in advance.)

---

(1) My answer (Revised the Constant Term for $time=t$)

\begin{eqnarray}
r_t &=& r_0 + \alpha t - \beta \int^t_0 r_u du + \sigma \int^t_0 \sqrt{r_u} dB_u\\
E[r_t | \mathcal{F}_s ] &=& E\left[r_0 + \alpha t - \beta \int^t_0 r_u du + \sigma \int^t_0 \sqrt{r_u} dB_u | \mathcal{F}_s \right] \\
&=& r_0 + \alpha t - \beta \int^t_0 E\left[ r_u | \mathcal{F}_s \right]du  + \sigma \int^s_0 \sqrt{r_u} dB_u + \sigma \int^t_s \sqrt{r_u}  E\left[ dB_u | \mathcal{F}_s \right] \\
&=& \left( r_0 + \sigma \int^s_0 \sqrt{r_u} dB_u \right)+ \alpha t - \beta \int^t_0 E\left[ r_u | \mathcal{F}_s \right]du
\end{eqnarray}

- (Revised the Constant Term for $time=t$) Let $u_t = E[r_t | \mathcal{F}_s ]$ with a condition of $u_s=r_s$, namely $u_s = E[r_s | \mathcal{F}_s ]=r_s$. Then, above equations come to below (O.D.E).

\begin{eqnarray}
E[r_t | \mathcal{F}_s ] &=& \left( r_0 + \sigma \int^s_0 \sqrt{r_u} dB_u \right) + \alpha t - \beta \int^t_0 E\left[ r_u | \mathcal{F}_s \right]du \\
u_t &=& \left( r_0 + \sigma \int^s_0 \sqrt{r_u} dB_u \right)+ \alpha t - \beta \int^t_0 u_u du \\
du_t&=& \alpha dt - \beta u_t dt \\
\frac{du_t}{dt}&=& \alpha - \beta u_t 
\end{eqnarray}

- (1st Step) Consider $u_t/dt = 0 - \beta u_t $.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{du_t}{dt}&=&  - \beta u_t\\
  %\int^t_0 \frac{du_s}{u_s} &=& - \beta \int^t_0 ds\\
  %\log \frac{u_t}{u_0} &=& - \beta t\\
  %\frac{u_t}{r_0} &=& e^{- \beta t} \\
  u_t &=& r_0 e^{- \beta t}
  \end{eqnarray}
- (2nd Step) Adjust $u_t$ satisfies the condition of $u_s=r_s$ 
  \begin{eqnarray}
  u_t &=& r_0 \left(1 - e^{- \beta (t-s)} \right) + r_s  e^{- \beta (t-s)} 
  \end{eqnarray}
- (3rd Step) Consider $u_t/dt = \alpha - \beta u_t $. Adjust $u_t$ as below.

\begin{eqnarray}
u_t &=& \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \left(1 - e^{- \beta (t-s)} \right) + r_s  e^{- \beta (t-s)}
\end{eqnarray}

- This satisfies the initial O.D.E. One reaches the solution as below.

\begin{eqnarray}
E[r_t | \mathcal{F}_s ] &=&u_t \\
&=& \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \left(1 - e^{- \beta (t-s)} \right) + r_s  e^{- \beta (t-s)}
\end{eqnarray}

$\square$

(2) Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODE approach is fine, but involved. There is a more convenient way to derive the results, especially so for $E_s[r_t^2]$. The trick is to work with $x_t=e^{\beta t}r_t$ and its corresponding sde is simply,

$$dx_t=e^{\beta t}(\alpha dt +\sigma r_t^{\frac{1}{2}}  dB_t) $$

Its solution in terms of $x_s$ can then be written as,

$$x_t= x_s + \alpha \int_s^t e^{\beta \tau} d\tau + z_{s,t}  $$

where $E_s[z_{s,t}]=0 $. Therefore,

$$E_s[x_t]= x_s + \frac{\alpha}{\beta}(e^{\beta t}-e^{\beta s} ). \tag{1} $$

The process for $x_t^2$ according to Ito's formula is,

$$dx_t^2=e^{\beta t}x_t(2\alpha + \sigma^2) dt + 2\sigma e^{2\beta t} r_t^{\frac{3}{2}} dB_t $$

It's solution in terms of $x_s$ is,

$$x_t^2= x_s^2 + (2\alpha + \sigma^2) \int_s^t e^{\beta \tau}x_{\tau} d\tau + zz_{s,t} $$

where, again, $E_s[zz_{s,t}]=0 $. Then, its expectation becomes,

$$E_s[x_t^2]= x_s^2 + (2\alpha + \sigma^2) \int_s^t e^{\beta \tau}E_s[x_{\tau}] d\tau . $$

Plugging the result (1) to obtain,

$$E_s[x_t^2]= x_s^2 + (2\alpha + \sigma^2) \int_s^t e^{\beta \tau}
\left[ x_s + \frac{\alpha}{\beta}(e^{\beta \tau}-e^{\beta s} )\right] d\tau . $$

Carrying out the integration to get,

$$E_s[x_t^2]= x_s^2 + (2\alpha + \sigma^2) \left[ \frac{1}{\beta}(e^{\beta t}-e^{\beta s} )x_s + \frac{\alpha}{2\beta^2}(e^{\beta t}-e^{\beta s} )^2  \right] \tag{2}$$

In the end, rewrite (1) and (2) in terms of the original variable $r_t$ to get the final results,

$$E_s[r_t]= e^{-\beta (t-s)}r_s + \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \left[1-e^{-\beta (t- s)} \right]$$

$$E_s[r_t^2]= e^{-2\beta (t-s)}r_s^2 + (2\alpha + \sigma^2) \left[ \frac{1}{\beta}(e^{-\beta (t-s)}-e^{-2\beta (t-s)} )r_s + \frac{\alpha}{2\beta^2}(1-e^{-\beta(t-s)} )^2  \right].$$

Comment: I agree with your way of thinking.\\

The ODE approach has been wonderful since Feynman–Kac theorem was established, but it has the disadvantage that analytical solutions cannot be developed without genius discovery.\\

Thank you for giving me the real genius proof in a short time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you on the main lines with the answers 1). 
To be more rigorous, I would say :
\begin{align}
E[r_t | \mathcal{F}_s ] = r_0 + \alpha t - \beta \int^t_0 E\left[ r_u | \mathcal{F}_s \right]du + \sigma E\left[\int^t_0 \sqrt{r_u}   dB_u | \mathcal{F}_s \right] \tag{A}
\end{align}
But $\int^t_0 \sqrt{r_u}   dB_u $ is a martingale, therefore $E\left[\int^t_0 \sqrt{r_u}   dB_u | \mathcal{F}_s \right]= \int^s_0 \sqrt{r_u}   dB_u$. Hence, $(A)$ becomes:
\begin{align}
E[r_t | \mathcal{F}_s ] = r_0 + \alpha t - \beta \int^t_0 E\left[ r_u | \mathcal{F}_s \right]du + \sigma  \int^s_0 \sqrt{r_u}   dB_u
\end{align}

Denoting $u(t)=E[r_t | \mathcal{F}_s ]$, we have the following ODE:
\begin{align}
u'(t) &= \alpha - \beta u(t) \quad \text{for }0\leq s\leq t\ \\
u(s) &= r_s 
\end{align}

For the question $(2)$, we apply first the Ito's lemma to the function $\phi(x) = x^2$ (which is $C^2$ and the process $r$ meets the conditions of an Ito process.)
\begin{align}
dX_t = d(r_t^2) &= 2r_tdr_t +d\langle r\rangle_t\\
&= 2\left[(\alpha r_t - \beta r_t^2)dt - \sigma r_t^{3/2}dB_t\right] + \sigma^2 r_tdt \\
&= 2\left[(\alpha \sqrt{X_t} - \beta X_t)dt - \sigma X_t^{3/4}dB_t\right] + \sigma^2 \sqrt{X_t}dt \\
&= (2\alpha +\sigma^2)\sqrt{X_t}dt - 2\beta X_tdt - 2\sigma X_t^{3/4}dB_t]
\end{align} 
Therefore,
\begin{align}
X_t = X_0 + (2\alpha +\sigma^2)\int_0^t\sqrt{X_u}du- \int_0^t 2\beta X_udu - \int_0^t 2\sigma X_u^{3/4}dB_u]
\end{align} 
Taking the conditional expectation, we have:
\begin{align}
E[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s ]  = X_0 + (2\alpha +\sigma^2)\int_0^tE[\sqrt{X_u}| \mathcal{F}_s ]du- \int_0^t 2\beta  E[X_u| \mathcal{F}_s]du - E[\underbrace{\int_0^t 2\sigma X_u^{3/4}dB_u}_{martingale}|\mathcal{F}_s]
\end{align} 
Denoting $v(t) = E[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s ]$ and taking the derivative, we have the following ODE:
\begin{align}
v'(t) &= (2\alpha + \sigma^2)u(t) - 2\beta v(t)\quad \text{for }0\leq s\leq t\ \\
v(s) &= r_s^2
\end{align} 
Note that I used the Fubini theorem to switch between the integral and expectation.

Comment: Well if you wanna be really rigourous. First you should show that a solution exists for the SDE (and as the coefficient are not lipschitz you have to use strong theorem for this). Second you can only say that $\int^t_0 \sqrt{r_u}  dB_u$  is a local martingale and it is not obvious (but it is true) that it's a martingale, you can prove $\int^t_0 r_u du $ is $L^2$ for this to be true. Even though the way you put it, using $Y_s= E[\int^t_0 \sqrt{r_u} dB_u|\mathcal{F}_s]$ if you can prove that $\int^t_0 \sqrt{r_u}dB_u $ is integrable. Third $X_s$ is a local martingale, the same remark applies...

Comment: I agree, we need to show that $Z_t = \int_0^t\sqrt{r_u}dB_u$ is a martingale. To do so, we can show that $E[\int_0^t\langle{Z}\rangle_udu] < \infty$, so that $E[\int_0^tr_udu] < \infty$ (not $\int_0^tr_udu \in L^2$ as written in your comment). But this quit trivial by taking the expectation of $(A)$ and solving the ODE. I don't think to we need to show the existence of the SDE solution here. But all of this should be a preliminary work that (I suppose) OP has already done.

Comment: yep sorry for te typo L^2 for L^1 and note that the same is needed for  $\int_0^t 2^2\sigma^2 X_u^{3/2}du$

Comment: Thank you finding out my typos.
I revised the constant terms for $time=t$.

Comment: Thank you very much, how to set up O.D.E. However, the last explanation is short of words and other readers find it difficult to understand.I assume that you are assuming that other readers know the following ODE terms, so I will add that.

\begin{eqnarray}
v(t)&=&p(t)+w(t) \\
p(t)&=&\zeta+\xi e^{-2 \beta(t-s)}\\
v'(t)&=&p'(t)+w'(t) \\
w'(t)&=&-2\beta w(t)
\end{eqnarray}
Because $w(t)$ comes to $ce^{-2 \beta(t-s)}$, one has to modify $c$, which satisfies the condition of $v(s)=r_s^2$.