# How can I derive the mean and the variance of the Cox-Ingersoll-Ross model by Ito’s lemma?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

According to Wikipedia and some other articles I’ve seen the mean of the CIR model :
$dr_t=a(b-r_t)dt+σ\sqrt r_t dW_t$

Is the following :
$E(r_t) =r0e^{-at}+b(1-e^{-at})$

And the variance :
$ Var(r_t)=r0\frac{σ^2}{a}(e^{-at}-e^{-2at})+\frac{bσ^2}{2a}(1-e^{-at})^2$

I have tried to derive it with Ito’s lemma by taking a function $r_te^{at}$  and solving this function with the Ito lemma formula however my mean and variance results were very different. I’m preparing for an exam and my professor only wants us to solve these stochastic differentials with Ito's lemma

I’m super frustrated I can’t come to the correct answer. Could anyone more experienced with stochastic calculus enlighten me ? Thanks :)

- I have seen a similar question on here however it wasn’t solved by itto’s lemma

My approach was:

- to take the function $x=e^{at}r_t$

And use the Itos lemma formula:

$e^{at}dr_t +ae^{at}dt$

Now substituting the original CIR model $r_t$ into drt
$abe^{at}dt+ae^{at}r_tdt+e^{at}σ\sqrt r_t dW_t+ae^{at}r_t dt$

$ \int_{0}^{t} abe^{at}\,ds + \int_{0}^{t} ae^{at}r_t\,ds + \int_{0}^{t} e^{at}σ\sqrt r_t dW_t\,ds $

E(X) = $x0+2e_te^{ab}+be^{at}-ab-2ar_t+ \int_{0}^{t} e^{at}\sqrt r_t dW_t\,dt$

V(X) = $[x0+2e_te^{ab}+be^{at}-ab-2ar_t+ \int_{0}^{t} e^{at}\sqrt r_t dW_t\,dt]^2$

My second approach was  taking the function $e^{bt}r_t$
I followed the same procedure , after taking ittos lemma ,
$be^{bt}r_t dt + e^{bt}dr_t$
And substituting drt with the CIR equation

$be^{bt}r_t dt+ ab e^{bt}dt+ ar_te^{bt}dt+e^{bt}σ\sqrt r_t dW_t$

$\int_{0}^{t} be^{bt}r_t \,ds + \int_{0}^{t} ab e^{bt} \,ds + \int_{0}^{t} ar_te^{bt} \,ds + \int_{0}^{t} e^{bt}σ\sqrt r_t dW_t \,ds$

$E(x) = x0 +(e^{bt}-1)rt+ ae^{bt}-a + \frac{ar_te^{bt}}{b}-ar_t +  \int_{0}^{t} e^{bt}σ\sqrt r_t dW_t \,ds $

$V(x) = [x0 +(e^{bt}-1)rt+ ae^{bt}-a + \frac{ar_te^{bt}}{b}-ar_t +  \int_{0}^{t} e^{bt}σ\sqrt r_t dW_t \,ds]^2 $

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Cox-Ingersoll-Ross Model (1985)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3328585/the-cox-ingersoll-ross-model-1985)

Comment: Never mind and apologies. The CIR SDE has no known explicit solution. The linked duplicate question has an answer that uses Ito's lemma on $x_t=e^{\beta t}r_t$ to solve your problem.

Comment: Please edit your question showing your attempt.

Comment: Edited :) might be messy

Comment: Yes messy. From $x_t=e^{at}r_t$ I get $dx_t=ae^{at}r_t\,+e^{at}dr_t.$ Then from the CIR SDE: $dx_t=ae^{at}r_t\,dt+e^{at}(ab-ar_t)\,dt+e^{at}\sigma\sqrt{r_t}\,dW_t\,.$ It looks like you have a sign error because here the two $e^{at}r_t\,dt$-terms must cancel.

Comment: Thank you for your time  I’ll look into it